# ActiveMQ without persistence

Tags: java, configuration, activemq-classic, messagebroker

I'd like to set up a publisher-subscriber based communication protocol between a server producing messages and many clients receiving them. After a bit of research, I decided to go with ActiveMQ. I looked at a few tutorials and the ActiveMQ site and set up the broker as follows:

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.setPersistent(false);
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
broker.start();
```

I only need the message passing functionality, no database persistence or anything alike. However, when I start the application, a activemq-data folder is created regardless of the the configuration. This in turn causes an exception the next time I start the broker.

```
SEVERE: Failed to start ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker. Reason: java.io.EOFException: Chunk stream does not exist at page: 0
```

Is this a bug or am I not setting up the broker correctly (using ActiveMQ 5.4.1)? How can I disable persistence, so the additional data storage is not created? Also, I prefer to configure the broker from within the Java application and not through an xml file.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: For now I found a workaround of deleting the folder every time I start the broker/publisher. Would be great if anyone could shed some light on that issue anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal behaviour but a bug in KahaDB (the default persistence store in Activemq)

You can see info on [Bug 2935 of ActiveMQ](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2935).

You could solve this by choosing a different persistence engine, although i strangly had this problem a couple of times and then it dissapeared

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Changing the persistence store would add another dependency for something I don't intend to use.

Comment: so basically you do not want persistence and it's not taking the code configuration. What i've read is that the setting will be ignored when a persistence adapter is set. Maybe you could try clearing the adapters ( incase one has been set by default, altough looking at the source, it uses the MemoryPersistence) before starting ? Other then that, i would say it is a bug an needs to be registered in jira :s

Comment: As I said, I don't want to introduce another dependency (for MemoryPersistence). I guess I just have to wait until 5.5 is going to be released. Postings in the bug report suggest that the bug will be fixed in this version.

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in 5.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

In my case remove all of the kahadb data files from the following directory helps:

```
$ ls /var/lib/activemq/main/data$ cd kahadb
db-1.log  db.data  db.redo  lock
```

then:

```
sudo service activemq restart
```

and everything back to work

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the delivery mode for your message producer.

```
messageProducer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
```

Integer values allowed by JMS are:

```
    int NON_PERSISTENT = 1;
    int PERSISTENT = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

if using maven pom, then switch to 
`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`
also don't forget to clear out the contents in KahaDB and Scheduler.
it also helps to turn the scheduler off, if not needed.