# Failed to browse topic exception in ActiveMQ logs

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, middleware

I am using ActiveMQ v5.10.

Am unable to understand root cause of exception am getting in my logs.

```
[20141116 13:07:30.288 EDT (ActiveMQ Broker[broker] Scheduler) org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Topic#doBrowse 615 WARN] - Failed to browse Topic: cometd. 
ProxyPush
java.io.EOFException: Chunk stream does not exist, page: 34 is marked free 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction$2.readPage(Transaction.java:470) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction$2.<init>(Transaction.java:447) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.openInputStream(Transaction.java:444) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.load(Transaction.java:420) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.load(Transaction.java:377) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.index.BTreeIndex.loadNode(BTreeIndex.java:262) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.index.BTreeIndex.getRoot(BTreeIndex.java:174) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.index.BTreeIndex.iterator(BTreeIndex.java:232) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase$MessageOrderIndex$MessageOrderIterator.<init>(MessageDatabase.java:2757) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase$MessageOrderIndex.iterator(MessageDatabase.java:2739) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore$3.execute(KahaDBStore.java:526) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:779) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.recover(KahaDBStore.java:522) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyTopicMessageStore.recover(ProxyTopicMessageStore.java:62) 
        at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyTopicMessageStore.recover(ProxyTopicMessageStore.java:62) 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Topic.doBrowse(Topic.java:578) 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Topic.access$100(Topic.java:65) 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Topic$6.run(Topic.java:703) 
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.java:33) 
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) 
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Though this exception is infrequent and occurs sometimes but am wondering what could be cause of it.

Please note that broker and client communication is fine. client is able to send and receive messages on that topic but exception is continuously coming. There is no durable subscriber on this topic. Messages sent on this topic are non-persistent.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951220/activemq-without-persistence). seems to be some bug in KahaDB persistence Engine

Comment: I am using ActiveMQ 5.10 and this bug was fixed in 5.4.2 itself. Am I missing anything ?